# How to store big text resources in Android (up to 100mb)

Tags: java, android, text-files, large-files

I want to make text reader in Android. There are 20000 text files with summary size of, maybe, up to 100mb. The application must be able to read the texts offline.
I do not know how to implement it. If we put all the texts in the apk-file, it will turn out giant-sized (4mb of apk + 100mb of text). It can be more convenient to store the text in a single file? Maybe I can use archives? Maybe I can use a swap file after installing?
Help needed! Thanks!

Comment: not actually the stackoverflow question. you can store your content on the device (SD card memory, internal storage) and your application can just find them in filesystem and open or you can store them somewhere and your application will donwload data after being installed. there are dozens of possible ways

Comment: Look at the saving files part of the Android Developer site. It shows all storage option you need to know : internal and external, public or private. It also shows how to read and write to a file and how to handle permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an app with 300 Mb text. I uses SQlite DB because i needed fast search in my case. Then I archived DB, put in assets and extract on first run. Result archived DB was 56 Mb. In your case you may do the same. But you don't need use a sqlite if you don't need search, relation data etc. Is not so much choice really,  database or text files depending on the requirements

Comment: Thanks! What archiver you have used? (ZIP, 7z - what the best for plain text/json?)

Comment: I used [zip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)